# asp.net undefined getting text value from ajax post

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I can not get value parameter **description** from ajax post, this value is undefined, but  **c_id** and **status** i can.
The problem here is take the text data from ajax post.
How to get this **description** parameter ?
Tks all.

```
 function Reset_Status(obj) {
        $.ajax(
              {
                  type: "POST",
                  async: false,
                  url: "Tasks.aspx?t_id=" + $(obj).prev().val() + "&status=" + $(obj).val() + "&description=update" ,
                  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert('Error: ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
                  }, success: function () {
                      //alert('Succsess')
                  }
              })
    }
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Update();
}
private void  Update()
{
    string s = "";
    int c_id=0,status=-1;
    c_id=Utils.GetDefautInteger(Request.QueryString["C_id"].ToString(), 0);
    status = Utils.GetDefautInteger(Request.QueryString["status"].ToString(), 0);
    s = (Request.QueryString["description"].ToString(); return;}
```

string s is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo here `s = (Request.QueryString["description"].ToString(); return;}`

Try

```
s = Request.QueryString["description"].ToString();
```

And then just remove the `return` and leave the `}` alone on the last row. Like so:

```
private void Update()
{
    string s = "";
    int c_id=0, status=-1; c_id=Utils.GetDefautInteger(Request.QueryString["C_id"].ToString(), 0);
    status = Utils.GetDefautInteger(Request.QueryString["status"].ToString(), 0);
    s = Request.QueryString["description"].ToString();
}
```